# Importing Active Directory objects using LDIFDE or CSVDE

Tags: active-directory

I'm going to make some changes on an Active Directory environment (mainly deletions), before doing so I'd like to make backup of few objects using `LDIFDE` or `CSVDE`.

The distinguished names of these objects contains non-latin characters, some of its attributes might aswell.

I think the unicode support is the reason for my complication.

When exporting I  use the `-m` flag.

What I've tried so far is to export an object using `LDIFDE` twice, with and without the -u flag, then importing each of these files using `-i` flag and `-u` flag.

The first errors I got were "`Directory object does not exists`", after some time I was able to get something like "`the last token..`"

When using CSVDE all I get is the "`Directory object does not exists`", I have tried the same procedure with that tool.

I'm seriously stuck, I don't have any idea what to try next, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exporting the objects, why not just take a backup of your Active Directory Database, incase you need a restore?  You would do this by completing a System State backup.

Comment: Being a part of an organization, I don't have permissions for the entire active directory but only a specific part.

Comment: `Being a part of an organization, I don't have permissions for the entire active directory but only a specific part.` - Well then you should be working in concert with the people that do have "permissions" for the entire organization. Let them know what you plan to do, ask them to make sure they have backups and ask them for any guidance you think you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are many attributes exported as you can guess when you use LDIFE.  Some of these attributes are not able to be imported as they are owned by certain System processes.  You can do exactly what you're asking for though and [this is a great guide for doing so.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/muaddib/archive/2012/01/08/backing-up-active-directory-objects-using-ldifde.aspx?Redirected=true)

Let me know if you need more help and I can explain further.

Comment: Tried it, I got syntax error once more...

Comment: Screenshot, or text please for reference?  If it's a simple syntax error then you're almost there.